# Javascript setInterval works but not infinite loop

Tags: javascript, html, dom, setinterval

I don't understand why the infinite loop does not work but uncommenting the function call works.

```
<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas"style="border:2px solid black;" width="1600" height="900">
    Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>
<script>
    var c = document.getElementById ("myCanvas").getContext ("2d");
    var boxSize = 25;
    var numBoxes = 1;
    var x = 1000;
    var dx = 1;
    var y = 100;
    var dy = 1;
    var a = 0.01;
    var da = 0.1;
    var size = 20;
    var w = c.canvas.width;
    var h = c.canvas.height;

    //function testing () {
    while (true) {
        c.clearRect (0, 0, w, h);
        x = x + 1;
        y = y + 1;
        a = a + 0.1;
        x = x + dx;
        y = y + dy;
        if (x < size / 2 || x + (size / 2) > w) {
            dx = -dx;
            da = -da;
        }
        if (y < size / 2 || y + (size / 2) > h) {
            dy = -dy;
            da = -da;
        }
        c.save ();
        c.translate (x, y);
        c.rotate (a);
        c.strokeRect (-size / 2, -size / 2, size, size);
        c.restore ();
    }

    // testing ();
    // setInterval (testing, 10);
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: `while(true)` seems like a good way to crash a browser ?

Comment: I know, but why doesnt it work?

Comment: Just curious why setInterval, but not requestAnimationFrame?

Comment: As I tried, both works setInterval and while, but the thing is that while triggers to fast and soon your browser crash.. http://jsfiddle.net/r5jZE/2/

Answer (score 3):

When you use `setInterval` you keep adding the function you are calling to the queue of things for the browser to do. Repaint events are also added to this queue.

When you use an infinite loop, the browser never gets to the end of the function, so it never gets around to running a repaint and the image in the document never updates.

Comment: I dont quite understand. Sorry if this is naive, but wont the whole loop repaint the rectangle?

Comment: Because it is too busy running the code in the loop for the function that repaints the page to run.

Comment: Ah I see that know. Who adds the repaint event to the browser queue?

Comment: The browser does that automatically. You just need to let it have time to run it.

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript-in-a-browser is a part of a larger construction. You need to align to the rules of this construction and don't hurt it. One of the rule is that your JavaScript *must* run quick and *exit* then. Exit means that control gets back to the framework, which does all the job, repaint the screen etc.

Try to hide and show something many times:

```
for (n = 0; n < 200; n++) {
  $("#test").hide();
  $("#test").show();
}
```

When this code runs, you won't see any flickering, you will see that the last command will have effect.

Have to say, it's not easy to organize code that way, if you want to make a cycle which paints nice anims on a canvas, you have to do it without *while*.